# Wp ajax - не срабатывает callback функция из functions.php после выполнения ajax

Tags: php, wordpress, ajax

Подскажите что может быть причиной того что после того как успешно сработал ajax запрос в Вордпресс, не вызывается повешеная на него функция?

1. В functions.php регистрирую обработчик и колбек

```
// Определяем колбек
        if( wp_doing_ajax() ){
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_baly', 'baly_function' );
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_baly', 'baly_function' );
        }
        function baly_function(){
          echo $_POST['baly'];
          echo ('eeeeeeeee');
          wp_die();
        }
```

2. В js файле плагина пишу что передавать в запросе

```
        //передача на сервер
              jQuery.ajax({
                url:  ajaxurl,
                type: 'POST',
                data:{'action': 'baly',
                      'baly' : baly},
                success: function(data){
                 console.log(baly);
               },
                error: function(){
                console.log('ERROR');
                }
             })
```

3. На вкладке Network вижу что запрос успешно прошел
   [image: kolback]
   А как понять почему тогда не вызвалась функция из файла functions.php?

Дополню вопрос...я случайно нашел что ответ мне вывелся на вкладке response. Значит колбек отработал. Просто я ожидал что он сработает как стандартный вывод echo php на экран.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хотя по идее все вызвалось, только почему на вкладке Response а не как стандартное echo в шаблоне. Я хочу результат вывести на экран пользователю. Или это надо делать только через Jquery?

Comment: В данном примере в ajax есть ключ success с data, data - это результат функции baly_function(). Соответственно, для вывода полученных данных их нужно как-то вывести, например alert(data)